# What does the "bother" mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

> A: Oh bother the Sex Discrimination Act. Surely they can't force me to take on a married woman.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a problem with this question being asked here, but you might want to consider asking similar questions at the newly-started [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) site on the Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

From Eric Partridge, *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, Fifth Edition, (1961):

> Both *bother* and *botheration* are used as exclamations. [OED] 3. *I'm* or *I'll be bothered* is a disguised form of swearing (see **bugger** v., 1): coll[oquial] :probably from the 1860's.

*Bother* in its stand-alone, annoyed exclamation sense was a favorite expression of Winnie-the-Pooh, I believe. But in the example above, the word probably is serving as a euphemism for *bugger*.

Comment: *And that's what I mean when I say or I sing/Oh, bother the flowers that bloom in the Spring* (from Gilbert & Sullivan's *The Mikado*). I believe you'll hear it often in various contexts from that great philosopher, Winnie the Pooh, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic expression *bother the X* usually means that X is an onerous requirement to do something I consider undesirable OR X is a barrier to something that I really want to do.

It is related to the adjective *bothersome*, meaning vexing or causing trouble.

In this context, it indicates in a nicely abbreviated form the thought "It appears that the Sex Discrimination Act will limit my freedom of action in recruiting new staff in ways with which I do not agree."